# How to split a string and get all values?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I've got this small piece of example code in my View

```
@{
    string MyValue = "val1;val2;val3";
 }
```

And I am wondering how I can split it where there's a semi colon, and then I can run through each value and print it in an  list

Comment: var list = MyValue.Split(';')

Comment: [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks, it was because I was using ";" instead of ';'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that in a View when using the @{} most C# code can be used. You can use this line with a loop to get what you need done.

string sub = input.Substring(0, input.indexof(";"));